# File exists but cannot be executed from another folder

Tags: linux, fedora

On my Fedora 16 machine, I have an executable file named 'WarpImageMultiTransform', and I can run it when I cd into the folder that contains it:

```
[huangchao@localhost bin]$ ./WarpImageMultiTransform --help
Usage: 
./WarpImageMultiTransform ImageDimension moving_image output_image  -R reference_image --use-NN   SeriesOfTransformations--(See Below)
```

But when I try to run it from other folder, it says the file doesn't exist:

```
[huangchao@localhost antsIntro]$  ls /home/huangchao/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin/WarpImageMultiTransform
/home/huangchao/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin/WarpImageMultiTransform
[huangchao@localhost antsIntro]$ ./home/huangchao/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin/WarpImageMultiTransform --help
-bash: ./home/huangchao/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin/WarpImageMultiTransform: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` at the beginning of a path means the path is relative to the current directory. `/` means it's an absolute path. This command:

```
ls /home/huangchao/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin/WarpImageMultiTransform
```

lists absolute directory. But your second command:

```
./home/huangchao/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin/WarpImageMultiTransform --help
```

Means: "execute `/home/huangchao/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin/WarpImageMultiTransform` **relatively to my current directory**". This will work only if your current directory is `/`, as it will be equivalent to calling it without the period.

You need the period only to execute files from current directory, other dirs (relative or absolute) don't require a period.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Just using

```
[huangchao@localhost antsIntro]$ /home/huangchao/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin/WarpImageMultiTransform --help
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have easy access to an executable from any directory, you can add the location of the executable file to your `$PATH`. On *nix systems, if a word is typed into a terminal, the system will search through the directories in the user's path to find an executable with that name.

- To see your current $PATH do

  ```
  echo $PATH
  ```
- To add a directory called `new_dir` to your $PATH **for the current session only** do

  ```
  PATH=$PATH:/new_dir
  ```
- To add a directory called `new_dir` to your $PATH for every session (assuming you are using bash), add this line to your `$HOME/.bashrc` file

  ```
  PATH=$PATH:/new_dir
  ```

So, in your case, you would add this line to `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/huangchao/ANTs-1.9.x-Linux/bin/
```

You will then be able to execute `WarpImageMultiTransform` simply by typing the command name wherever you are.